# Are signatures in Preview shared over iCloud?

Tags: icloud, preview

In Preview on both my iMac and MacBook I can annotate a PDF with my signature, which I find useful. I remember setting this up on my iMac, prior to doing a clean install of macOS, but not on my much newer MacBook. Would my MacBook and rebuilt iMac have pulled the signatures in from iCloud?

Comment: Perhaps there is a way, bu as far as I can tell signatures are not shared over iCloud. I just tried it with two macs that I have signed in on the same account and it didn't sync.

Comment: It seems to have worked on my account, but not my wife's.